# Is this a memory leak in Guzzle middleware?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, guzzle6

Does the following output shows a memory leak?
My worker server is running out of memory. Although its a stable allocation but its not freeing up the memory after the execution.

Here is the issue https://github.com/guzzle/oauth-subscriber/issues/47#issuecomment-148480943

```
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Oauth\Oauth1;

function stack_it()

{
  $stack = HandlerStack::create();

  $middleware = new Oauth1([
    'consumer_key'    => NULL,
    'consumer_secret' => NULL,
    'token'           => NULL,
    'token_secret'    => NULL,
  ]);
  $stack->push($middleware, 'oauth_1');

  $stack->remove('oauth_1');
}

echo 'initial: '.memory_get_usage().PHP_EOL;
for ($i=0; $i < 20; $i++)
{
  $this->stack_it();

  gc_collect_cycles();
  echo memory_get_usage().PHP_EOL;
}

die();
```

**Output**

```
initial: 3818976
4282040
4282040
4282040
4282040
...
4282040
4282040
4282040
4282040
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are witnessing is the normal memory consumption of the `HandlerStack`. I refer you to the source for [HandlerStack](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/HandlerStack.php#L38).  The fact that memory usage does not increase with each successive iteration is indication that there is no leak.

You will notice that when `HandlerStack::create()` is called,  support for cookies, HTTP error exceptions, redictions, and preparing a body before sending are added to the handler.